# Java compilation error "variable not found" persisting

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

I am new to java programming and as i was learning abt some theory when i came across a term "Test Cases". Now i know its pointless to think of test cases when u don't even have a solid working program but i wanted to start small.

so i wrote a very basic program to check a no. for even or odd.
and i added an exception handling block in it.

here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

class eveodd 
    {
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        int num;
        System.out.println("Enter the no. ");

        try 
        {
            Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
            num=a.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please only enter an integer"); 
        } 
        finally 
        {
        num=a.nextInt();
        }

        if (num%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println(" No. entered is an Even No. ");
        }

        else
        {   
            System.out.println("No. entered is a Odd no. ");
        }   
    }
}
```

And Here is the output :

[image]

Please tell me how to fix this.
kindly modify the code and bold the section

Thanks all :)

Comment: Declare `a` before the `try`.

Comment: declare as a what ? i mean data type ?

Comment: Declare `a` in higher scope so that it's visible.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: You're trying to use `a` in the finally block, but its scope is limited to the `try` block you declared it in, with `Scanner a`. Just move that declaration above the try-catch-finally block.

Comment: _pointless to think of test cases when u don't even have a solid working program_  Not true!  See [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and [ATDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_test%E2%80%93driven_development)!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/  hope this helps for not commiting the mistake again

Comment: @AndrewS Hey. I just read the Test Driven Development link. Yes. i get that point. In this type of development test cases become the main source of improvement right from simplest developed cycle. Thanks man. I appreciate it.

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala : So if i have a global variable i declare it just below class and if i have a variable that is only used in a specific method i declare it within the method. That's it yeah ?

Comment: @VehitVerma - You can declare fields for the class and individual instances outside the methods. Ideally, these are private to the class, and not globally accessible. Ideally, variables declared within the method are given the minimum scope possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is out of scope in the `finally` clause. You should declare it *before* the `try-catch-finally` block, as in

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    num=a.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please only enter an integer"); 
} finally {
    num=a.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Hey ! It worked. Thanks very much :)